# Entering Grub Rescue mode after installing kali from usb to a hard disk?

Tags: boot, kali-linux, grub, boot-loader

I downloaded kali 32bit images from Official Kali website, then installed on my existing windows 7 machine erasing and creating a single partition.

Now, after rebooting

```
error: no such device: b8b6b11d-0755-...

Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I couldn't rescue from the boot mode since my keyboard has no H key to type the following to repair grub

How to Solve this issue , I tried this link but did'nt help much as it cannot find /bash/shell for chroot command

https://gist.github.com/embs/5822439

Comment: In that linked solution you need to boot from a different Linux disk and chroot into the one you are trying to fix.

Comment: yes . i boot from live usb disk  but it was the same error

Comment: Can you run `grub-install /dev/sdX` ? X being the drive that has Kali Linux installed on it. If not please re-install Kali, verifying that you have installed GRUB to the proper drive.

Comment: @kemotep ,  it returns an error, `File system ext2 not support embedding`

Comment: see if any of [these solutions](https://superuser.com/a/1213967/874967) can help.

Comment: @kemotep yes .  it was okay now and even i tried a reboot but its still not loading from the hard disk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75315/discussion-between-kemotep-and-coffemug).

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. It's a simple matter that grub can't find where Kali Linux is installed but why that is after a default install or if the partition even exists is unknown. You're best off rescuing with a live cd. Are you sure you didn't install kali linux to a flash drive or your install media?

Comment: @kemotep , thanks for your tips. I resolved this issue  by partitioning hard disk and  specifically pointed ` /boot` and   `/swap` to  `/dev/sda1 `and  `/dev/sda2 `

Comment: @jdwolf , installing through USB drive and the issue was solved by making two partitions and  separating boot and swap on each partition.i am not sure its the right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think most 32bit distros are dying, and unless your laptop/computer is older than ~2008, I would recommend using a 64bit version.

Make sure your BIOS settings are all correct, specifically your boot priorities. Make sure when you're trying to boot from your hard disk, you don't have your usb disk plugged in.

I've often times been stuck with a bad installation for whatever reason, and had to reinstall. Maybe try reinstalling and carefully walking through all the partitioning steps to make sure it's all correct.

Comment: I tried this multiple times and everytime its not booting from the hard disk where i installed.  i  tried ubuntu and was fine and then yeah i am using   an older laptop